# how to auto close session query connection f3 fat-free framework posgresql

Tags: postgresql, fat-free-framework

how to auto close session query connection fat-free framework
how to auto close session query connection
at the end of the script
at the end of the script
at the end of the script
select * from table
f3 fat free framework versi 3.7